# Does HSM also include the history of technology?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic

I want to ask why the V-2 rocket was made with ethanol and liquid oxygen, which had a specific impulse of [215 seconds at sea level](http://www.astronautix.com/lvs/v2.htm), when a solid rocket using APCP gets [237 seconds](http://www.astronautix.com/stages/shulesrb.htm). In addition, a solid rocket engine would have almost no moving parts, so it would be a lot cheaper and quicker to manufacture.

I'm guessing that, what I would be effectively asking is: Why was APCP not available or not developed at that time? What is the developmental history of solid rockets?

Is the history of technology on topic for this site?

Comment: It might fall into the [tag:engineering] category.

Comment: [Posted.](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/why-was-the-v-2-not-a-solid-rocket-and-or-what-is-the-scientific-history-of-sol)

Comment: In addition, several computer science tagged questions are really about computer technology http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-science I think it turns on the nature of a question: if it focuses on history of an invention we are the closest site in the network, if it is more about specifics of how it worked Engineering SE might be a better fit. http://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7):

As this site is currently still in beta, its scope is not *completely* fixed yet. Of course, the rough outline is clear, but there is plenty of space to try things out and I think that this is a good opportunity to do so.

Instead of giving you a definite yes or no, I suggest you post your question and see how it is received by the community. Perhaps you could post a link to this meta post as a comment for members to discuss its on- or off-topicness if they feel the need to.